# Single event sent from silverlight application recorded twice in google analytics report

Tags: silverlight, google-analytics, analytics

I am using MSAF (https://msaf.codeplex.com/) for implementing GA tracking in a silverlight application.Whenever I send a event to google analytics it is being recorded as 2 events.This is the sample code I am using:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GA.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
    xmlns:Microsoft_WebAnalytics_Behaviors="clr-namespace:Microsoft.WebAnalytics.Behaviors;assembly=Microsoft.WebAnalytics.Behaviors"
    xmlns:ga="clr-namespace:Google.WebAnalytics;assembly=Google.WebAnalytics"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="Main" Background="White">
         <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ga:GoogleAnalytics WebPropertyId="UA-XXX-1"></ga:GoogleAnalytics>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <Microsoft_WebAnalytics_Behaviors:TrackAction Category="App Accessed"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**EDIT**: When I inspected the network traffic from the app I could see two http requests going to the google analytics servers for the GIF.The 1st request has a status code 200 and the 2nd request has a status code 304

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with this code.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Seems like MSAF is not updated since '12. I would recommend that you skip MSAF and use the measurement protocol instead. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/